# Changing class signiture

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-search .search-query {
  color: #515151;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #111111;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
```

Hi, I am new to css and have started to use **bootstrap**, I have to change the background color of a search input box with class `.search-query`. The above css code is used from *bootstrap.css*. If I change the `background-color` in above class, does it effect the `.navbar-inverse and .navbar-search` also? Why is this class defined with `.navbar-inverse .navbar-search .search-query { }` and not simply `.search-query {}` ? Does this mean three classes have same signature or the .search-query class will be applied when it is under `navbar-inverse and .navbar-search` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `CSS` question not so much a `bootstrap` question.

In `CSS` if you separate 2 selectors with space their significance is as you deduced "only for the .search-query contained within a navbars-search".

```
element1 element2 {
    /*
     * applies to any level of descendance 
     *     <element1><element2></element2></element1>
     * or
     *     <element1><x><element2></element2></x></element1>
     */
}

element1, element2 {
    /*
     * applies to either <element1></element1> or <element2></element2>
     */
}

element1 > element2 {
    /*
     * applies only to direct children <element1><element2></element2></element1>
     */
}

element1 + element2 {
    /*
     * applies only to immediately preceding siblings
     *     <x><element1></element1><element2></element2></x>
     */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS above affects `.search-query` which is nested in a `.navbar-search` which is nested in `.navbar-inverse` and therefore will not affect a `.search-query` which is not nested into those class containers.

However, changes only affect the `.search-query` class and not the other two classes. It is just to be more specific about selectors.